# What is initialised first - controller or partial/html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Hi please explain reason for following three scenarios as I am unable to know why is this happening -

1)

```
<div ng-controller="myctrl">
 <p>something for DOM manipulation</p>
</div>
```

2)in route I write

```
('someroute',{
 templateUrl : "mytemplate",
 controller : "myctrl"
});
```

mytemplate:

```
<div>
 <p>something for dom manipulation</p>
</div>
```

3)

```
<div ng-include="mytemplate" ng-controller="myctrl"></div>
```

with template being same as above

The controllers in all the above scenarios are same, and in all of them I am just trying to select p tag of DOM by writing angular.element('p'). But this seems inconsistent. It works very well in 2nd scenario, it never works in 3rd scenario and I am not sure about 1st sccenario. Can someone explain which method is best for dom selection/manipulation, as I have to add a class to this 'p' tag on hover.

I am not understanding which gets initialized first- controller or partial?

Comment: controller. then it loads partials

Comment: if you are trying to use `angular.element` you are probably doing something wrong, unless you are designing some extreme edge case.  You ***definitely*** don't need `angular.element` to modify an element's class on hover.  Start with trying to use `ng-class`.

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev - in which scenario controller is initialized first?

Comment: @Claies - thanks. But the above written code is just very simplified version of my problem. I really need to select DOM element

Comment: @Vineet'DEVIN'Dev. you just test it with Network of browser

Comment: I don't want to get into an extended debate regarding this issue, but I do say, with lots of evidence to draw on if necessary, that using `angular.element` is *almost never* necessary.  It is an indication that you are trying to change the DOM in some manner inconsistent with your DATA, or in some way that the DATA can't control.  This is a major code smell in angular, unless you can demonstrate some proof that this is the only way.  This "simplified version" doesn't illustrate your problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating DOM inside controllers is discouraged. Quote from [Best Practice - Dom Manipulations](http://ng-learn.org/2014/01/Dom-Manipulations/):

> Dom Manipulations should not exist in controllers, services or anywhere else but in directives.

If you only need to style elements on hover, using the `p:hover` CSS selector would be enough without touching the DOM. `ng-class` and [`ng-mouseover`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover) can help you if you really want the class.

For more complex scenarios, you may want to write your own directive. You can check the article above for a guide to do that.

---

Load order from the first case: **HTML first.** Directives like `ngController` are loaded after parsing the HTML. Therefore the HTML already exists when the controller is loaded.

Load order for the second case: I'm not sure about it. You may check documentation for [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) or [uiRouter](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site) depending on the router you are using.

Execution order for the third case: **Controller first.** The directive [`ngController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) have higher priority than the [`ngInclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) directive. Therefore, the controller is loaded first.

Quote from [ngController documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) :

> This directive executes at priority level 500.

Quote from [ngInclude documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) :

> This directive executes at priority level 400.

Comment: Hi, You are correct, but I need it as my actual code demands DOM selection. And I can't select DOM in 3rd scenario only. When I write something like this - angular.element('p').length, I get 1 in 2nd scenario but 0 in 3rd scenario.

Comment: You can move the `ng-controller="myctrl"` attribute to your template file in that case. P.S. Even if you do need DOM selection, you can still do it in a directive instead, unless you cannot even modify the controller code.

Comment: yeah its working, but I already got this point. Thanks. Still my question is not actually answered. I dont know which gets initialized first - controller or partial in all these scenarios?

Comment: @Vineet'DEVIN'Dev I have added a section explaining the load order as requested.